# Check if time is within time bounds with minutes

Tags: javascript, html

looking for help in changing the working hours from 8 to 5 to 8:30 to 5:30. would appreciate some help with amending the existing JavaScript function:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

onload = function ( )
{
var now = new Date();
var weekday = now. getDay();
var hours = now.getHours();
if ((hours >= 8) && (hours <= 5)) && ((weekday >=1) && (weekday <= 5))
    {
    document.getElementById("status").src="open.png";
    }
else
    {
    document.getElementById("status").src="closed.png";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="status" src="">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you mistakenly added extra bracket in your if expression:

if ((hours >= 8) && (hours <= 5)) && ((weekday >=1) && (weekday <= 5))

---

I ecountered this seemingly easy to solve in past, until you need to compare the minutes inbetween, you will run to unecessary complex logic.

the cleanest way to solve this is convert into "seconds from midnight" which makes easier for comparison between two time. (this technique similar to UNIX TIME technique use by lots of date system nowdays, you can google it)

in smaller project its ok to do following:

```js
var now = new Date();
var weekday = now.getDay();

function getSecond(hours, minutes){
    return ( (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) ); //this will return the total seconds past midnight
}

//converting to seconds to certain point of time is used by "timestamp" technique, you can google bout it
let openSeconds = getSecond(8,30);
let closeSeconds = getSecond(17,30);
let nowSeconds = getSecond( now.getHours(), now.getMinutes());

console.log(openSeconds + ' ' + closeSeconds + ' ' + nowSeconds);

if( (weekday >= 1) && (weekday <= 5) ){ //Weekday validation

    if(openSeconds < nowSeconds && nowSeconds <= closeSeconds){ //inclusive, ( < or <= ) you decide
        document.getElementById("status").src = "open.png";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("status").src = "closed.png";
    }  
}
```

in bigger project, i always always recommend to use dayjs or moment js to deal with timezones like explained in video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions and comments. Though some were unnecessarily complex, the solution I came up with is based on rickvian's feedback and i hope it has less brackets this time :)

````
<script>
onload = function ()
{
var now = new Date();
var weekday = now.getDay();
var hours = now.getHours(); 
var mintues = now.getMinutes();
if ( (weekday >= 1 && weekday <= 5) && (hours*60 + mintues) >= 510 && (hours*60 + mintues) <= 1050)
{
document.getElementById("status").src="open.png";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("status").src="closed.png";
}
}
</script>
````

Comment: @Fred you are welcome, i'd appreciate if you can upvote this answer, it means a lot to me

Answer (score 2):

Since `.getHours()` returns an integer, check the hour and the minutes accordingly using `.getMinutes()`.

It's a bit messy, but it's easy to understand. I've broken it down below the snippet.

```js
const cur = new Date();
const minutes = cur.getMinutes();
const h = cur.getHours();
const d = cur.getDay();
let closed = true;
if ((d >= 1) && (d <= 5)) {
  if (h > 8 && h < 17) {
    if (h == 8 && minutes < 30 || h == 17 && minutes > 30) {
      closed = true;
    } else {
      closed = false;
    }
  } else {
    closed = true;
  }
} else {
  closed = true;
}
console.log("Closed? : " + closed);
```

- `(d >= 1) && (d <= 5)` - this checks whether the weekday is within the bounds of Monday (1) and Friday (5)
- `(h > 8 && h < 17)` - is the current hour within the bounds 8 AM and 5 PM (8 and 17 respectively)?

  - `h == 8 && minutes < 30 || h == 17 && minutes > 30` - if the current hour is 8, check if the minutes is smaller than 30. We need to ensure that the minutes is 30 or greater (8:30+). If the current hour is 5, check if the minutes is greater than 30. We need to ensure that the minutes is 30 or less (5:30-). If any of these are satified, we know it is closed.

Here's a comprehensive snippet with logs:

```js
const cur = new Date();
const minutes = cur.getMinutes();
const h = cur.getHours();
const d = cur.getDay();
let closed = true;
if ((d >= 1) && (d <= 5)) {
  console.log("Weekday is within Monday and Friday? check");
  if (h > 8 && h < 17) {
    console.log("Hour is between 8 AM and 5PM? check");
    if (h == 8 && minutes < 30 || h == 17 && minutes > 30) {
      console.log("Minutes is more then 30 if hour is 8 or minutes is less than 30 if hour is 15? fail");
      closed = true;
    } else {
      console.log("Minutes is more then 30 if hour is 8 or minutes is less than 30 if hour is 15? check");
      closed = false;
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Hour is between 8 AM and 5PM? fail");
    closed = true;
  }
} else {
  console.log("Weekday is within Monday and Friday? fail");
  closed = true;
}
console.log("Closed? : " + closed);
```

**Here's what it should look like in your particular example:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    onload = function() {
      const cur = new Date();
      const minutes = cur.getMinutes();
      const h = cur.getHours();
      const d = cur.getDay();
      let closed = true;
      if ((d >= 1) && (d <= 5)) {
        if (h > 8 && h < 17) {
          if (h == 8 && minutes < 30 || h == 17 && minutes > 30) {
            closed = true;
          } else {
            closed = false;
          }
        } else {
          closed = true;
        }
      } else {
        closed = true;
      }
      if (closed) {
        document.getElementById("status").src = "closed.png";

      } else {
        document.getElementById("status").src = "open.png";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="status" src="">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the code you posted:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var now = new Date();
  var weekday = now.getDay();
  var hours = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  
  // if Monday - Friday
  if (weekday >= 1 && weekday <= 5) {
    
    // if before 8am OR after 5pm
    if (hours < 8 || hours > 17) {
      status.src = 'closed.png';
    }
    
    // if less than 30 minutes past 8am, OR
    // if 30+ minutes past 5pm
    else if (minutes < 30 && hours === 8 || minutes >= 30 && hours === 17) {
      status.src = 'closed.png';
    }
    
    // if 30 or more minutes past any hour between 8am and 4pm,
    // or up to 29 minutes past 5pm, you're open!
    else {
      status.src = 'open.png';
    }
    
  }
  
};
```